# Neo4j percentage query

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I recently had a Homework problem that I could not figure out how to even start let alone how to get each of the 1 letter purposes added together and have their % returned. I have included the Neo4j model as well as a list of the first few rows. The data showed the Taxon, Class, Order, Family, Genus if they were imported/exported and the purpose (example C. Aves imported for commercial purposes)
What % of trades fall under each purpose type (bred, captured, wild, zoo, etc...)

CLASS:     ORDER:         IMPORT/EXPORT:   PURPOSE:
AVES       Falconiforms   43 Exported      S (Science)
Mammalia   Carnivora      2 Exported       H (hunting)
Reptilia   Crocodylia     10 Imported      S (Science)
Aves       Anseriformes   2 Imported       T (commercial)
Mammalia   Primates       700 Exported     T (commercial)

Neo4j Graph Dataset

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far? Did you import/create data? The cypher online course might help you neo4j.com/graphacademy. Basically you need match the pattern, count (distinct) occurrences and then divide.

Comment: I have tried this, but I am getting zeros instead of the correct percentages. MATCH (s:Species) - [:TRADED_IN] -> (t:Transaction) WITH s.Class as Animals,t.Quantity as total,  count(t.Quantity) as totalTraded RETURN count(Animals)/sum(totalTraded)*100, Animals ORDER BY toUpper(Animals) ASC

Comment: these are the totals for each                                                                    class "sum(totalTraded)"│"Animals"
│2449 -"Actinopteri"
│3 -"Amphibia"                                                                                 
│665 - "Anthozoa"
│1746 -"Aves" 
│1 - "Bivalvia"
│2 - "Coelacanthi"

Comment: and this is what I get when i use the above code "count(Animals)/sum(totalTraded)*100"│"Animals"       
│0 - "Actinopteri"   
│100 - "Amphibia"      
│0 - "Anthozoa"      
│0 -"Aves"          
│100 - "Bivalvia"